# Some questions before starting with the PIC32

Tags: pic, embedded

I am not completely new to embedded systems, but need to brush up/learn several topics like OS, C, C++, Networking, microprocessors, etc for an exam that I have to take.

I have some interest in microchip's PIC32, but not sure if it's fit for me.

- Can you just use the data sheets and app notes, or is a book needed?
- Are microchip microcontrollers designated for industry-grade projects on the PIC32 and go to market? -
- Are there PIC32 RTOS for free?

Comment: Its too broad and the only real question in there is "can I get a good RTOS for free to use on the PIC32?". Everything else can be answered by "it depends".

Comment: You're wondering whether a PIC 32 can be used for commercial projects? Seriously!!? Try to actually *think* about it. What else do you imagine they are for? How would the occasional stray hobbyist buy enough of them to make these products remotely profitable? Hobbyist volumes are 0% of the overall business, probably 0.0%, or maybe even 0.00%.

Comment: also digilent makes an Uno32 that is basically an arduino that runs on a pic(2x as many pins and about 4x as fast as the arduino).. which can be helpful for prototyping

Comment: @OlinLathrop: I might have been a bit naive, but here in India there seems to be a whole industry dedicated to servicing student engineering projects. Hence the question.

Comment: When you look at the total volume of that "whole industry", I'm sure you will find it is still tiny compared to real commercial projects.  Hobbyists need to understand that they are largely irrelevant to the industry.  There may be resellers catering to hobbyists, but that volume is nowhere near what the component manufacturers need to sustain themselves.

Answer (score 5):

Aren't the answers to these questions fairly obvious?

> I want to know if getting a PIC32 from microchip is a good idea as I
>   would like to learn in a hands-on fashion rather than cramming from a
>   text book.

Yes, if you want to learn hands-on, you should get your hands on a chip (or preferably, an evaluation board). Or are you asking whether some other chip would be more suitable?

> I would also like to know if one can execute industry-grade projects
>   on the PIC32 and go to market (just out of curiosity). Thanks.

Again, yes. Do you really think Microchip would produce the PIC32 if it weren't suitable for high-volume industrial products? That's sort of the whole point.

> (Also, can I get a good RTOS for free to use on the PIC32?)

Yes. What do you see when you search for "free RTOS"?